# Zeal from the PPA has unmet dependences

Tags: ppa, software-installation, qt5

I'm trying to install [Zeal through ppa](http://zealdocs.org/download.html) in Ubuntu 13.04, but is giving the error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 zeal : Depends: libqt5core5 (>= 5.0.2) but 5.0.1+dfsg-0ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
        Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but 5.0.1+dfsg-0ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
        Depends: libqt5network5 (>= 5.0.2) but 5.0.1+dfsg-0ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
        Depends: libqt5sql5 (>= 5.0.2) but 5.0.1+dfsg-0ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
        Depends: libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.0.2) but 5.0.1+dfsg-0ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
        Depends: libqt5xml5 (>= 5.0.2) but 5.0.1+dfsg-0ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to install [qt5-qtwebkit](https://github.com/jkozera/zeal/issues/80#issuecomment-31442692) but keeps the same error. Any clue what could be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add two ppa's to install Zeal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jerzy-kozera/zeal-ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install zeal
```

This is since zeal depends of Qt5, which is not available in repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Zeal has an official PPA. You can use that to install it.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:zeal-developers/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install zeal
```

Now you can search for `zeal` app or you can launch it from terminal using `zeal` command.

This install zeal without any problems. I have used other PPA's also but they failed because of unmet dependencies.