Ubuntu has unmet dependencies


after upgradation of Ubuntu, It ran into error Oh no something went wrong.A problem has occured and system cant recover.
tried using ctrl + alt + f3 to open console and cant do anything
Recommends: libpython3.12-stdlib but it is not going to be installed libreadline-dev: Depends: libreadline8t64 (= 8.2-4build1) but it is not going to be installed openssl Depends: libss13t64 (>= 3.0.9) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution). pranay@pranay-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt install aptitude
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
aptitude: Depends: aptitude-common (= 0.8.13-5ubuntu5) but it is not going to be installed Depends: libapt-pkg6.0t64 (>= 1.9.11") but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libboost-iostreams1.83.0 (>= 1.83.0) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libcwidget4 (>= 0.5.18-1) but it is not going to be installed Depends: libxapian30 (>= 1.4.19~) but it is not going to be installed
gnome-settings-daemon: Depends: gnome-settings-daemon-common (42.1-1ubuntu2.2) but 46.0-1ubuntu1 is to be installed gnome-shell: Depends: gir1.2-gnomebg-4.0 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-3.0 (>= 42.3) but 42.0-5 is to be installed Depends: gir1.2-gnomedesktop-4.0 (>= 40) but it is not going to be installed Depends: gir1.2-gweather-4.0 (>= 4.1) but it is not going to be installed Depends: gir1.2-mutter-14 (>= 46.0) but it is not going to be installed Depends: gir1.2-nma4-1.0 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: gir1.2-soup-3.0 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: gir1.2-webkit-6.0 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: gnome-shell-common (= 46.0-0ubuntu6~24.04.4) but 42.9-0ubuntu2.2 is to be installed
Depends: libatk-bridge2.0-0t64 (>= 2.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libatk1.0-0t64 (>= 1.12.4) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libecal-2.0-3 (>= 3.45) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libedataserver-1.2-27t64 (>= 3.45) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libgjs0g (>= 1.73.1) but 1.72.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.3 really.is.1.72.2.0ubuntu2 is to be installed Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.79.0) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libgnome-desktop-4-2t64 (>= 40) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libgtk-4-1 (>= 4.12.0) but 4.6.9+ds-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 is to be installed
Depends: libica13t64 (>= 3.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libmutter-14-0 (>= 46.0) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libpipewire-0.3-0164 (>= 0.3.10) but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: evolution-data-server (>= 3.45) but 3.44.4-0ubuntu1.1 is to be installed Recommends: gnome-control-center (>= 1:42) but 1:41.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.8 is to be installed
gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng Depends: gir1.2-gnomeautoar-0.1 but it is not going to be installed gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock Depends: gnome-shell (<43) but 46.0-0ubuntu6~24.04.4 is to be installed libatk-adaptor: Depends: libatk-bridge2.0-0t64 (>= 2.52.0-1build1) but it is not going to be installed Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.62) but it is not going to be installed
libgck-2-2 Depends: libglib2.0-0164 (>= 2.79.0) but it is not going to be installed libgcr-4-4 Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.79.0) but it is not going to be installed libpython3.12-minimal Depends: libss13t64 (>= 3.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: libpython3.12-stdlib but it is not going to be installed
libreadline-dev: Depends: libreadline8t64 (= 8.2-4build1) but it is not going to be installed openssl Depends: libss13t64 (>= 3.0.9) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution). pranay@pranay-VirtualBox:"$ 

It gives back same error whatever apt install commands I run, and same for sudo apt --fix-broken install also
Zeal from the PPA has unmet dependences had a look at this, but in my case Ubuntu got upgraded and I ended here, unlike I am trying to install some package
had a look at How to fix broken 24.04.1 LTS upgrade which has missing software?, it is similar but yet a different question, for me even sudo apt full-upgrade command gives a unmet dependency error

This question is similar to: Zeal from the PPA has unmet dependences. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The most common cause, by far, of this kind of apt issue is that you have some non-Ubuntu or wrong-release deb package that requires the older packages. Locate and remove that incompatible software. Then the rest of your system can upgrade properly. If you need more help, then copy/paste the complete output of sudo apt update into your question above.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/410145/zeal-from-the-ppa-has-unmet-dependences
had a look at this, but in my case Ubuntu got upgraded and I ended here, unlike I am trying to install some package

This question is similar to: Major software missing after 24.04.1 LTS upgrade. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

had a look at How to fix broken 24.04.1 LTS upgrade which has missing software?, it is similar but yet a different question, for me even sudo apt full-upgrade command gives a unmet dependency error -- Did you first fix the software sources as described in that answer? Did you run sudo apt update after that

yes sudo apt update runs fine,but sudo apt upgrade throws the unmet dependancies issue back

Did you fix the sources from jammy to noble? Can you post a screenshot of sudo apt update output?

yeah i have added the output of sudo apt update @ArchismanPanigrahi

At this point, it may be easiest to fresh install ubuntu 24.04

Cmon, any other way? @ArchismanPanigrahi

@user535733 It is there https://i.sstatic.net/tC4ZrEOy.png. It seems that it only has noble, and not jammy, so it seems to be normal. Bad thing is that, packages related to libapt/aptitude are having dependency issues, so removing all problematic packages and reinstalling ubuntu-desktop is not an option

Ugh. Images instead of copy/paste. Hard to work with. Hard to read.
